# SQL query structure and PDO, does bad query structure allow SQLi possibility?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Okay so I have been web developing for a little while now and I have some questions regarding PDO and SQL injection. As we all know SQL injection is a horrible vulnerability that we all want to avoid to our basic capability. I understand that SQL injection is most commonly done by using ' in a data which breaks the query,
such as the infamous:

```
' or '1'='1
```

I sometimes get lazy and usually my PDO SQL queries end up like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?
```

(I'd then bind ? to the `$_GET['id']` or something)
Now notice I don't use ` or ' anywhere in the query, is SQL injection still possibly after prepared statements? What exactly does prepared statements stop? Thank you!

Comment: to answer your final question: prepared statements stops injection techniques by encapsulating and escaping the string before the query is actually executed.

Comment: Don't think of parameter binding as string substitution, wherein you're just placing a string wherever `?` lies.  The RDBMS receives the _value_ you place in `?` and uses it as a value. It does not dynamically construct a SQL statement from it, so it is _not_ vulnerable if used correctly.

Comment: Using bound parameters `?` _eliminates the need_ for manually quoting your parameters, and indeed if you did quote `'?'`, the literal string `?` would be passed to MySQL with no substitution at all (actually, you'd get an error trying to bind to a nonexistent param `?` before the statement was even executed.)

Comment: As long as you're using bound parameters they are escaped properly, there are certain cases where there are other vulnerabilities(Learn about them [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)). To address them, add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`